# Windows phone 8: display pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-phone-8, componentone

I need to display PDF files in my windows phone 8 app.
The easiest way I know is using ComponentOne pdf control. But it is way too costly to be bought by an individual. 
Is any body aware of a free wp8 control for diplaying pdfs?

My next option is to create it my self. I am trying to convert the pdf into an image and then display it. But I can not find any wp8 compatible library. I tried GhostScript but it is not working with windows phone 8.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need an internal reader? If the user has a PDF reader installed on the phone, you can use it to open the PDF file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118338/how-to-open-pdf-files-in-windows-8-application-using-c

Comment: Hi @abhinav pandey its great to hear that you have solved your problem using MuPDF. I want to implement same in one of my project, would you like to share your thought, how you achieve this?

Comment: @gofor.net sure thing, what do you wanna know?

Comment: I want to open/view pdf inside my windows phone application. How I will implement into my application? If you can show any sample code then it would be really appropriated.

Comment: Are you making a PDF reader you just need to show a file? To implement a full PDF reader in an app is not a good idea(in my opinion). It is altogether a different scenario if you are trying to make a PDF reader.

Comment: Yes I want to show only PDF using this MuPDF. I don't want to search for other app installed on device to view PDF. You can check my question for that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039818/how-to-detect-default-pdfviewer-and-open-pdf-in-windows-phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [MuPDF](https://github.com/MishaUliutin/MuPDF.WinRT), Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 WinRT component?

> MuPDF.WinRT is a lightweight PDF, XPS and CBZ viewer and
>   parser/rendering WinRT component.
>
> The MuPDF.WinRT is just wrapper under MuPDF library
>   (http://www.mupdf.com/),  so it can support the same functions as
>   MuPDF library

Might be helpful : [Reading PDF and XPS on your Windows 8 application using WinRT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/04/15/reading-pdf-and-xps-on-your-windows-8-application-using-winrt.aspx) [It uses MuPDF.]

Comment: Thanks.
MuPDF.WinRT did the job.

Answer (score 1):

Аpitron PDF Rasterizer for .NET works on windows phone, they even have they own pdf viewer